# Requesting Client Certificate a second time with cefsharp

Tags: cefsharp

I am developing an application that requires the user to select a client certificate to authenticate, and do so by overriding the OnSelectClientCertificate method of the browser's request handler.

On initial authentication this works fine, but I want to be able to allow the user to logoff while keeping the application open and reauthenticating with a different client certificate. the problem is that OnSelectClientCertificate never seems to be called again. Have tried deleting all cookies and calling CloseAllConnections but still no luck.

Does anyone know the solution to this?

Comment: From memory the selection is cached,  it's not a feature that I've ever used, my only suggestion is seeing if the selection is cached per RequestContext, see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#request-context-browser-isolation for creating browser with different settings. If that doesn't work then asking on https://magpcss.org/ceforum/index.php to see if what you are attempting is actually possible. Remembering that CefSharp is just one of many chromium embedded framework wrappers.

Answer (score 0):

did manage to find a solution to this problem, it is as amaitland said that the certificate selection was cached per RequestContext, so to get it to prompt again I moved away from using the global RequestContext and instead used a new RequestContext whenever I needed to prompt for a client certificate again.